# Simple Play Slick Setup for Unit Testing

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, slick

I used play-slick for Slick integration and Guice to inject DAOs. Evolutions to create tables and populate seed data i.e. `1.sql, 2.sql, ...`. I am almost complete and I want to split my Evolutions files and `application.conf` into 2 environments.

I created 2 sets of `conf/application.conf` and `test/conf/application.test.conf` pointing to different databases for testing and live deployment. I have setup build.sbt to use `application.test.conf` for `test`,

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=test/conf/application.test.conf"
```

`application.test.conf` content,

```
slick.dbs.h2test.driver = "slick.driver.H2Driver$"
slick.dbs.h2test.db.driver = org.h2.Driver
slick.dbs.h2test.db.url = "jdbc:test.h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
```

How do I configure my test cases / suites to use `h2test` context (ie. `conf/evolutions/h2test/1.sql`) instead of `default` to populate test data and run Slick queries again `h2test`? I tried to use `FakeApplication` and `GuiceApplicationBuilder` ways with limited success. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I see my [play-slick example](https://github.com/knoldus/activator-play-slick-app)

```
  class EmployeeRepositorySpec extends PlaySpecification{

     import models._

     "Employee repository" should {

       def empRepo(implicit app: Application) = Application.instanceCache[EmployeeRepository].apply(app)

    "get all rows" in new WithApplication()  {
      val result = await(empRepo.getAll)
      result.length === 4
      result.head.name === "sky"
     }

  "get single rows" in new  WithApplication()  {
      val result = await(empRepo.getById(1))
    result.isDefined === true
      result.get.name === "Vikas"
  }

   "insert a row" in new  WithApplication()  {
    val knolId = await(empRepo.insert(Employee("sky", "sky@knoldus.com",  "knoldus","Senior Consultant")))
     knolId === 5
    }

   "insert multiple rows" in new  WithApplication()  {
     val result = empRepo.insertAll(List(Employee("sky1", "sky1@knoldus.com", "knoldus","Senior Consultant"),
    Employee("sky2", "sky2@knoldus.com", "knoldus","Senior Consultant")))
      val knolIds = await(result)
     knolIds === Seq(5, 6)
    }

    "update a row" in new  WithApplication()  {
      val result = await(empRepo.update(Employee("sky", "sky@knoldus.com",  "knoldus","Senior Consultant", Some(1))))
      result === 1
     }

     "delete a row" in new  WithApplication()  {
       val result = await(empRepo.delete(1))
       result === 1
     }
    }

   def await[T](v: Future[T]): T = Await.result(v, Duration.Inf)

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I relooked this example and I found a solution to my other problems I had after I solved this.

Comment: This is already outdated. Indicating the Play version it ran with would be useful. Now it says "You do not have an implicit Application in scope. If you want to bring the current running Application into context, please use dependency injection.", and `PlaySpecification` does not exist.

Comment: @Sky I tried with specs2 `PlaySpecification`, too, but same error ("You do not have an implicit Application in scope."). I copied and pasted your code, I just don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I added `play.slick.db.default = test` to overwrite **default** in  `application.test.conf`. On top of that, I added

```
play.evolutions.db.default.autoApply = false
slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.H2Driver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "org.h2.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:h2:mem:nothing"
```

Otherwise, Evolution will also populate the other database defined by "default" and my "other database" was not running, it caused my test to fail because of a failed connection to a non exist database.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic class writing test cases for all repositories like this:

```
 class TestModel[T: ClassTag] extends WithApplicationLoader {
  lazy val app2dao = Application.instanceCache[T]

  lazy val repository: T = app2dao(app)

  def result[R](response: Future[R]): R =
    Await.result(response, 2.seconds)
}
```

And, Now pass your Test Class in TestModel to create an object from your test case like this:

```
class TestRepositoryTest extends Specification {

  private val modelTest = new ModelsTest[TestRepository]

  "Test Repository" should {

    "store a user" in {
      val testObj = Test(0, "test@example.com", new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis))

      val storeResult =
        modelTest.result(modelTest.repository.store(testObj))

      storeResult must equalTo(1)
    }
  }
}
```